# How to make the caption the same size as the footnotesize and always center the caption

Tags: floats, captions

I would like to make the caption the same size as the footnotesize and center the caption without having to use \captionsetup every time I insert a new picture.

```
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\captionsetup{justification=centering,margin=2cm}
\caption{Formas de onda da tensão e fluxo no estado estacionário}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{inrush_adptado.png}\\
{\footnotesize Fonte: Imagem adaptada de (Anderson,1999)}
\label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: There's no value in using `scale=1` as an image option, since that's the default.

Comment: Okay, didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: `scale=1` is similar to `angle=0` (which won't rotate), or `keepaspectratio` without any change in the width/height (and others)... you can keep it, but it won't change the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert `\captionsetup` in your document preamble. This would allow your settings to apply to *all* of the floats it's defined for, rather than placing them inside individual floats to achieve the same result.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption,graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{
  justification=centering,
  margin=2cm,
  font=footnotesize
}
\newcommand{\imagefootnote}[1]{%
  \par\addvspace{.5\baselineskip}
  {\footnotesize #1\par}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \caption{Figure caption}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image}
  
  \imagefootnote{Fonte: Imagem adaptada de (Anderson,1999)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot friend!